# Laravell. Вызов метода private внутри класса. Redirect внутри него

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


class MainController extends Controller {

public function index() {


    $this->firstmethod();

}

private function firstmethod() {

    return Redirect::route("test");

}
```

Почему не срабатывает Redirect?
Абсолютный новичок в php и laravel 5.

В routes.php все прописано!

Comment: `Redirect::route("test");` возвращает `RedirectResponse` объект, который, в свою очередь, должен возвращаться экшеном, т.е. `return $this->firstmethod();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index() {


    return $this->firstmethod();

}
```

Просто добавь слово return ;)

Comment: :D спасибо. Еще раз!